# svelte derived store returns Readable<Writable<boolean> | undefined> value

Tags: svelte, store, derived

How to do derived store right if value passed as readable store can be undefined? I have an object that contains `isLoading` value. Here the types example :

```
obj: Readable<{
isLoading: Writable<boolean>, 
loadData: () => Promise<void>,
....
}> | undefined
```

or

```
obj: {
isLoading: writable(false),
loadData: () => await fetch(),
}
```

When `loadData()` launches, `isLoading` is changing its value and i need to track state of this value.

so i have to make something like this (`obj` is in class):

```
const isLoading = derived(this.obj, (obj) => obj?.isLoading);
```

But it returns `Readable<Writable<boolean> | undefined>` and it is logical))) but i need `Readable<boolean>`

After some changes i got this

```
const isLoading = derived(this.obj, (obj, set) => active?.isLoading.subscribe(set))
```

turns out that it's working, but i am a bit confused because I don't really understand how it works and also TS returns `Readable<unknown>` . So, are there ways to get the value in a different way?

I know it can be really hard to understand the context without seeing all the code, so any answers and examples regarding derived store and undefined value will be welcome.

Comment: If obj is a store and you want to implement special methods in it, you have to make it a custom store and implement set and subscribe method (see custom store in doc)

Comment: I would not recommend having stores within stores in the first place.